# WebSocketListener OnMessage gets blocked and other incoming messages are enqueued

Tags: java, websocket, okhttp

I have implemented websocket client using okhttp 3.5.0 to connect to spring websocket server.

After websocket connection to server is successful, I subscribe to multiple topics to receive notifications from server. When a notification is received , if it takes long time to process that message in OnMessage function , I have observed that other incoming messages from server are enqueued and wait for the completion of first message .

Is there any way to make WebSocketListener OnMessage function concurrent, so that incoming messages does not wait for completion of any other older messages?

I tried delegating  the handling of messages to a separate thread and that solved the issue of onMessage getting blocked but  I want to know is there any other way to achieve the same.

This is my code to create websocket client

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    WebSocketListenerExtension webSocketListenerExtension = new WebSocketListenerExtension();
    client.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListenerExtension);
    // Trigger shutdown of the dispatcher's executor so this process can exit cleanly.
    client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```